# Always got "message": "Unauthenticated." - Laravel Passport

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I had find many tutorial this whole day. And my setup is exactly the same as all the basic tutorial out there.

Currently, i'm able to access `http://localhost/oauth/token` with successfully return token to me.

After that, i'm using ARC (Advanced Rest Client) to do the testing of calling my own api.

I had passed header such as

```
Authorization: Bearer the_token_here
accept: application/json
```

From that header, I just wanted to access the default API provided by laravel `/user`.

But, I always got response of `{ "message": "Unauthenticated." }`

Refer this tutorial https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-how-to-create-api-authentication-using-passport-example.html

I'm able to do login as per tutorial, but i'm unable to get data by endpoint `details`. It returning response of `{ "message": "Unauthenticated." }`

My route of `api.php`

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
    Route::get('/user', function( Request $request ){
        return $request->user();
    });
});
```

By the way, there are no error message in laravel.log and i had set to Debug mode

**UPDATE Thanks to Comment point out by Mayank**

```
League\\OAuth2\\Server\\Exception\\OAuthServerException: The resource owner or authorization server denied the request. in /.../vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/Exception/OAuthServerException.php:173
Stack trace:
#0 /.../vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/AuthorizationValidators/BearerTokenValidator.php(59): League\\OAuth2\\Server\\Exception\\OAuthServerException::accessDenied('Missing "Author...')
#1 /.../vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/ResourceServer.php(82): League\\OAuth2\\Server\\AuthorizationValidators\\BearerTokenValidator->validateAuthorization(Object(Zend\\Diactoros\\ServerRequest))
#2 /.../vendor/laravel/passport/src/Http/Middleware/CheckClientCredentials.php(46): League\\OAuth2\\Server\\ResourceServer->validateAuthenticatedRequest(Object(Zend\\Diactoros\\ServerRequest))
```

Comment: which middleware  assigned in route /user ??

Comment: Refer updated 'auth:api' @MayankMajithya

Comment: route must use after login .. are logged in ??

Comment: @MayankMajithya API doesn't need to be logged in to use it

Comment: please register this middleware in kernal.php , then use it

'client' => \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckClientCredentials::class,

Comment: use 'client' middleware for your route it may work

Comment: @MayankMajithya still getting the same message

Comment: token which generate using oauth/token , is it post method ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167409/discussion-between-mayank-majithya-and-kasnady).

Comment: Refer updated queestion @MayankMajithya I found out that the $request was empty in that class

Comment: @Mayank you should have posted your answer. Thats the only recipe worked out for me

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In order to get detail error message of the causes, you need to go to `CheckClientCredentials` class detail as below

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$scopes)
{
    $psr = (new DiactorosFactory)->createRequest($request);

    try {
        $psr = $this->server->validateAuthenticatedRequest($psr);
    } catch (OAuthServerException $e) {
        error_log($e->getHint()); // add this line to know the actual error
        throw new AuthenticationException;
    }

    $this->validateScopes($psr, $scopes);

    return $next($request);
}
```

Based on the error message. in my question.

The solution is adding this to `.htaccess` of root folder (not only inside the public folder)

```
# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

There's also a note in the official documents [refer here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#http-basic-authentication)

Without above configuration, the `Authorization` header will be ignored during call from anywhere to app. Once ignored, inside class will unable to retrieve this header data

Comment: Still got the error, I saw 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
in .htaccess already

Comment: @RobertTuanVuit need to be inside root folder and public folder

Comment: I was getting crazy because the auth was working fine in `local` but not in `staging`, after add the `rewrite` rules it totally works. 

But I would like to understand more in deep why they are necessary, any resource or wording about it issue?

Comment: h3. Update
I found why it is necessary, there is issues with basic auth in Apache and Passport, we are not using FastCGI module, but it is doing noise anyway.


We use php7_module.

As well, when debugging I totally comment the basic auth from `.htaccess` but not working without these rewrite lines.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#http-basic-authentication

Comment: where is CheckClientCredentials located in laravel project ?

Comment: This work for me I am using custom model But after that I am facing a new error i.e   "message": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'api_token' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `customer` where `api_token` = 30|tuzQtLks4kfvyqmSv35nE6e9MbPmwYFO2OZQxkJx limit 1)",

Answer (score 11):

In the event you’ve tried everything and nothing seems to work, try clearing your configuration cache. I spent two days reinstalling passport, following a billion tutorials, creating test projects etc. all to eventually realise I needed to clear my cache

`php artisan config:cache`

Comment: No. That command only clears the config cache. My command clears the config cache and re-caches the config. Type them both in and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: oh sorry did not know that, thought it only cached it.

Comment: is that happening when i use migration:rollback ???

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu, do the following.

Enable the rewrite mode.

`sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Go to `cd /etc/apache2`

Then open **apache2.conf** `nano apache2.conf` and find out the following line and change **AllowOverride None** to **AllowOverride All** as shown below.

```
# /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Finally, restart apache2 server

`sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone has the same problem, and the selected solution do solve it. Check the following:
**if you go alway respose{ "message": "Unauthenticated." }**
The solution is adding this to .htaccess of root folder (not only inside the public folder)

Options -MultiViews -Indexes

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Paste below code in .htaccess file in your project root folder.**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with Laravel 8 + Postman and I was encrypt password in Database to Bcypt (default laravel encrypt for password of Users model). I was resolve the problem.

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

Answer (score 0):

For those getting error message Unauthenticated even if the token is correct,
just replace laravel 8 prebuilt routes api:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

into

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I try (routes/api.php)

```
auth:api
```

instead of

```
auth:sanctum
```

It worked for me. I think cause using wrong guard.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 10

Make sure you have the set up the SESSION_DOMAIN and SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS set correctly.

Answer (score -2):

In case anyone has the same problem, and the selected solution do not solve it. Check the following:

1) Check you are sending the X-CSRF-TOKEN in the header of the request. In my case iḿ using vue with axios:

```
let token = window.$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token;
```

If you are sending it, try changing the following value in *vendor/laravel/passport/src/Passport.php* line 125 (may change)

From **True** to **False**

```
public static $unserializesCookies = false;
```

The issue may be similar to the one in https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/452

An explanation about serialization is in the issue

**UPDATE 01/02/2020**

As  *Zac Grierson* commented, vendors files should not be modified as they will change in the following

> composer update

*micksp* found a better **solution**: "**add protected static $serialize = false; to your app/Http/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php. Then remove your browser cookies.**"

Comment: You shouldn't modify the vendor files as they will change with `composer updates`.

Comment: @ZacGrierson agreed, but this answer did fix my problem all the others didn't. I can now look into fixing the problem more permanently

Comment: fixed! in the same issue (link in the answer): add `protected static $serialize = false;` to your app/Http/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php. Then remove your browser cookies.