# Laravel Passport API return Unauthenticated

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I am trying to authenticate api calls in my laravel application. I have installed Passport following the documentation and I think I have not missed anything. but API call returns a 401 Unauthenticated.

**Auth.php**

```
 'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
```

**AuthServiceProvider.php**

```
 public function boot() {

    $this->registerPolicies();
    Passport::tokensExpireIn(now()->addMinutes(config('auth.token_expiration.token')));
    Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(now()->addMinutes(config('auth.token_expiration.refresh_token')));

}
```

**RouteServiceProvider**

```
    $this->configureRateLimiting();

    $this->routes(function () {
        Route::prefix('api')
            ->middleware('api')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

        Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    });
```

**header**

[image: Header]

**and .htaccess**

```
 RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Comment: try adding token in postman's  Authorization>Bearer Token instead of header directly and run composer dump autoload command

Comment: @HuzaifaQidwai I try , but show message: Unauthenticated yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to register the necessary routes to issue tokens. Simply, you call `Passport::routes` method within the `boot` method.

```
 public function boot() {

    $this->registerPolicies();
    Passport::routes();
    Passport::tokensExpireIn(now()->addMinutes(config('auth.token_expiration.token')));
    Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(now()->addMinutes(config('auth.token_expiration.refresh_token')));

}
```

If you have any problems, tell me.

Comment: @Maryam
I am happy. My answer is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to *.htaccess* of root folder (not only inside the public folder)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

[Official documents refer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#http-basic-authentication)

[Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49446597/16098323)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @learner_323  Now , I try it and add this code to .htaccess root but not work and show Unauthenticated again